Depth of MRI burns
I've read plenty of cases where the patient received an MRI burn at the point where the hand touches the thigh, and various other situations involving skin burns or subcutaneous tissue burns (in which case the burn is not immediately noticeable).
Some examples:
https://www.ccjm.org/content/84/5/348
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0735675722003564
Study on SAR exposure with recommendations:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1155/2019/9618680
Another article:
https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC2998395/

About that time, our medical physicist asked me about some cases of burns or burning sensations reported by patients undergoing MRI at our institution. These cases seemed to exemplify situations in which at least the local SAR was anomalously high. In most, there was no association with the presence of other coils, external leads, or implants. The cases were investigated, and the manufacturer’s MRI service engineers were called. They invariably reported that the scanner was operating normally or within specifications

My question is, how would we know if a burn has occurred at an even deeper level? And if they typically don't, why not? Why are surface level burns more prevalent?

VTC as opinion-based.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
